# Problemas al subir la API a heroku

Tags: heroku

Cuando hago el comando "heroku container:push web -a nombreappheroku" me salta un error diciendo que no tengo imagen.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Prueba a meterte en el README y seguir los pasos del 3 en adelante

Comment: Alejandro, gracias por la respuesta pero es mejor tener la informacion que "enlazas" en el cuerpo de tu respuesta. Futuros usuarios lo tendrán más facil para acceder a la info. Un saludo